# Class fields and final variables

Tags: java

As far as I know to inside methods in anonymous inner class can use final varibles or class fields.
Is there a significant difference between them?
for example:

```
 final int[] intArr = new int[1];

Button testButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTest1);
testButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    intArr[0]++;
    Log.i("test", String.valueOf(intArr[0]));
  }
});

Button testButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTest2);
testButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    intArr[0]--;
    Log.i("test", String.valueOf(intArr[0]));
  }
});
```

I have 2 buttons and both them use **intArr[0]** and can get and set it value. The same behavior will be if I replace **intArr[0]** with some class fields like **private int value;** 
Based on this, I conclude that class fields and final variables are basically the same (I mean they are represented equally in the bytecode) and have difference only in scope and and the possibility to assign a value. 
Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (I mean they are represented equally in the bytecode)

Let's find out. Take this code

```
class Example {

  private static int[] outside = new int[]{1};

  public static void main(String [] args){
    final int[] inside = new int[]{2};

    Object inner = new Object(){{
      System.out.println(outside[0]);
      System.out.println(inside[0]);
    }};
   }
  }
```

Compile it to get two classes and then disassemble these using `javap -c` to get

```
class Example {
  Example();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #2                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return   

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_1      
       1: newarray       int
       3: dup           
       4: iconst_0      
       5: iconst_2      
       6: iastore       
       7: astore_1      
       8: new           #3                  // class Example$1
      11: dup
      12: aload_1       
      13: invokespecial #4                  // Method Example$1."<init>":([I)V
      16: astore_2      
      17: return        

  static int[] access$000();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #1                  // Field outside:[I
       3: areturn       

  static {};
    Code:
       0: iconst_1      
       1: newarray       int
       3: dup           
       4: iconst_0      
       5: iconst_1      
       6: iastore       
       7: putstatic     #1                  // Field outside:[I
      10: return        
}
```

and

```
final class Example$1 {
  final int[] val$inside;

     Example$1(int[]);
        Code:
           0: aload_0       
           1: aload_1       
           2: putfield      #1                  // Field val$inside:[I
           5: aload_0       
           6: invokespecial #2                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
           9: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
          12: invokestatic  #4                  // Method Example.access$000:()[I
          15: iconst_0      
          16: iaload        
          17: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
          20: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
          23: aload_0       
          24: getfield      #1                  // Field val$inside:[I
          27: iconst_0      
          28: iaload        
          29: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
          32: return        
    }
```

We see that the variable `inside` is created as a field inside the class `Example$1` whereas the variable `outside` is accessed via an automatically generated method `access$000` in `Example`. Therefore no - they are not represented equally in bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

A final variable is still a variable. The difference is that you can assign a value only once. Otherwise they behave the same. A field can also be final (although it is called a constant then), it's scope stays the same.

The `final` keyword is also called a "modifier" because it modifies the behaviour of a member rather then turning it into something entirely else.

Keep in mind that you can still change the objects a final variable points to. In your case you can modify the array although the variable is final. What you can't do is assign another array to your variable.

Answer (score 0):

`final` referes to the constant variables. you cannot change the value of constants. But you can change the value of non final member variables

Comment: Assuming OP referring object, I would rephrase answer saying, final variables references can't be modified (can't point to another object), but object state can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

A field in the outer class is referenced through `Outer.this`, which is effectively a `final` local. So in a way, there isn't really a difference. Obviously, `final` only has meaning for the variable, not the object it points to.

Imagine if you copied the outer `this` to a local `final` field in the enclosing method.

```
final Outer outer = this;
testButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

`outer` behaves the same as `Outer.this` within the anonymous inner class.